# Can Congress' rules be unconstitutional?

Tags: constitutional-law, congress, us-senate, constitutional-rights

I'm very interested in U.S. Constitutional law and do a lot of mock government. One of the questions that I have been considering is whether it is possible for a rule Congress sets for its proceedings to be unconstitutional. For example, I was recently considering the constitutionality of Senate Rule XIX, which reads

> No senator in debate shall, directly or indirectly, by any form of words impute to another Senator or to other Senators any conduct or motive unworthy or unbecoming a Senator.

This, to me, seemed like it could violate a Senator's First Amendment rights. Having [previously asked this question here](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/99453/constitutionality-of-restricting-a-senators-speech-for-unruly-behaviour-or-unpa), however, my understanding is that, by consequence of the Rulemaking Clause and the Speech and Debate Clause, the Courts cannot consider a question of the constitutionality of a house's rules and the question of whether a restriction imposed by those rules on any particular speech by any particular member is constitutional. And, in fact, that the only body that has the power to decide whether a Senate rule is inconsistent with the constitution is the Senate.

I am still unsatisfied with this answer, however. I was considering some extreme cases: What if the Senate whipped members to maintain order and decorum? What if a Senate rule enforced racial segregation? These are clearly illegal and unconstitutional. Can the Courts still not review such rules? If they can, how are those cases different from Rule XIX? I am rather confused and would appreciate help in understanding this. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

*United States v. Ballin*, [144 U.S. 1](https://tile.loc.gov/storage-services/service/ll/usrep/usrep144/usrep144001/usrep144001.pdf) (1892) asked whether a congressional rule relating to determining quorum comported with constitutional requirements. In deciding that the rule was valid, the Court said:

> Neither do the advantages or disadvantages, the wisdom or folly, of such a rule present any matters for judicial consideration. With the courts the question is only one of power. The Constitution empowers each house to determine its rules of proceedings. **It may not by its rules ignore constitutional restraints or violate fundamental rights, and there should be a reasonable relation between the mode or method of proceedings established by the rule and the result which is sought to be obtained**. But within these limitations all matters of method are open to the determination of the house...

That path to review is narrow (*Rangel v. Boehner*, [20 F.Supp.3d 148](https://casetext.com/case/rangel-v-boehner-5) (D.D.C. 2013)): "judicial intervention in this context is only 'appropriate where rights of persons other than members of Congress are jeopardized...'. judicial review of House Rules can take place only within a limited set of circumstances and may concern only a similarly limited set of constraints on the Rules. Here, Rangel does not challenge a particular House or Committee Rule as violative of the Constitution or of his fundamental rights."